# Trace inequality

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces, trace

Could you please give me a hint on how to prove the following inequality

$$\|u\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}\le C\|u\|^{\frac12}_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u\|^{\frac12}_{H^1}, \quad \forall u\in H^1.$$,

Comment: If $u$ is in $H_0^1$, then $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, so $\|u\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}=0$. So I certainly misunderstand something. But what?

Comment: My apologies for a confusion.
It should be $\|u\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}\le C\|u\|^{\frac12}_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u\|^{\frac12}_{L^2(H^1_0)}$ , $\forall u\in H^1_0$, $H^1_0=\{u\in H^1(\Omega): u=0\ \ \mbox{on}\ \ \partial\Omega\backslash \Gamma\}$

Comment: If so, you should edit your question instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How one could exploit continuity to go through?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: The way it currently stands, this question is unanswered. Are you sure the claim is correct?

Answer (score 4):

Typically, you get an estimate like
$$
\lVert u \rVert_{H^{s-1/2}(\Gamma)}
\le
C_s \, \lVert u \rVert_{H^{s}(\Omega)}
$$
for $s > 1/2$
by embedding theorems (maybe some regularity of the boundary is needed).
Here, $H^{s}(\Omega)$ is a fractional Sobolev space.

By interpolation theory, you get
$$
\lVert u \rVert_{H^{s}(\Omega)}
\le
C\,
\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1-s}\,
\lVert u \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)}^{s}.
$$
Combining the estimates, we have
$$\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Gamma)} \le C \, \lVert u \rVert_{H^{s-1/2}(\Gamma)} \le C \, C_s \, \lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1-s}\,
\lVert u \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)}^{s}$$
for all $s > 1/2$.
Maybe, one can trace the dependence of $C_s$ as $s \to 1/2$ to conclude something.

Comment: @gerw: Do you have a reference for $\|u\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} \le C \|u\|_{H^{1/2}(\Omega)}$? That's tantamount to boundedness of a trace operator from $H^s(\Omega)$ to $H^{s-1/2}(\Gamma)$ with $s = 1/2$ and I thought that's only possible for $s > 1/2$.

Comment: @gerw: btw, do you happen to know if $$\|u\| _{H^{1/2}(\Omega)} \le C\ \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1/2} |u|_{H^1(\Omega)}^{1/2}
$$
also holds (note the use of the $H^1$ half-norm rather than the full norm).

Comment: I don't think so. By Poincare, it holds for $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Otherwise, take a function, which is constant $\alpha$. Then, the right hand side is zero.

Comment: @gerw: Ah. Good point, thanks. Did you also see my previous comment?

Comment: You are right, I was sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

In Brenner, Scott: "The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods", 2nd edition, Springer-Verlag, New York (2002), the following theorem is stated (Theorem 1.6.6):

Suppose that $\Omega$ has a Lipschitz boundary, and that $p$ is a real number in the range $1\le p \le \infty$. Then there exists a constant, $C$, such that 
$$ \|v\|_{L^p(\partial\Omega)}\le C \|v\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^{1-1/p} \, \|v\|_{W^1_p(\Omega)}^{1/p} \quad \forall v \in W^1_p(\Omega).$$

A full proof is given only for the case of $\Omega$ being a unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$ and $p=2$. Hints for the proof of the theorem are given there.